# Can't load "Configure" tab

Tags: azure

On https://manage.windowsazure.com I can view and create websites. But if I select a website and click the Configure tab the browser just keeps loading for a very long time and eventually gives up. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Clear Your Browser Cache and Try again.